# Threadstart in a loop in a timer only executing last thread in said loop.

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

I have a timer executing a loop executing a series of threads. Each thread simply polls a serial device (on unique ports) and writes the data to a MySQL Database for pickup by a web application.

I am noticing only the last thread in the loop is being executed.

Here is my timer `Interval` method.

```
static void glob_timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (object[] row in user_ids)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row[0].ToString() + ":" + row[1].ToString());
        ThreadStart starter = delegate { Functions.UpdateFor(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString()); };
        new Thread(starter).Start();
    }
}
```

user_ids is a `List<object[]>` containing rows from a query; so `row[0]` = *user ID*, `row[1]` = *Com Port Name*

In the function `UpdateFor()`:

```
public static void UpdateFor(string uid, string com_name)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + uid + "]- " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + "Begin read transmission.");
```

When this is run, in the console I see

```
 1:COM1 
 2:COM2
 [2]-{DateTime} : Begin read transmission
```

Why am I not seeing the `UpdateFor` for uid 1.

Note: I have also verified the data that is supposed to be written to the DB from COM1 is never written.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I have about had it with all the "closing over the loop variable" problems people are having. This needs to be at least a warning in C# 5.0 (or some other solution). I'm not the first person to suggest it either...not even close. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are suffering from a closure problem. Each delegate captures the reference to `object[] row` in each loop, iteration, thus they all execute with the same reference, namely whatever the value of row ended up being. You need to simply assign an inner variable to make sure each delegate gets a unique reference.

```
 foreach (object[] row in user_ids)
 {
    var innerReference = row;
    Console.WriteLine(innerReference[0].ToString() + ":" + innerReference[1].ToString());
    ThreadStart starter = delegate { Functions.UpdateFor(innerReference[0].ToString(), innerReference[1].ToString()); };
    new Thread(starter).Start();
 }
```

Comment: will implicit or explicit type make a difference?