# Updating vertices on separate thread in Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, unity-game-engine

I have a fluids simulation running in Unity, calculating a heightfield for the fluid. I then have a mesh/vertex grid for which I set the height. I'm now trying to make it threaded. I only update the fluids every several frames (this is also threaded and works perfectly so far.) I also only update the mesh when the simulation got updated.

I have the following (non-threaded) code that works as it should:

```
public override void ApplyVisuals(float[][] lowerLayersHeight) {   
    UpdateVisuals(1, N, lowerLayersHeight, _height, _opaqueHeight, _nonZeroHeightOffset, _tempVertices, _tempColors);

    _mesh.vertices = _tempVertices;
    _mesh.colors32 = _tempColors;
}
```

So I update the visuals with some parameters, and then store the new vertices and new colors for the mesh in `_tempVertices` en `_tempColors` respectively. Though I tried to run this code on a separate thread:

```
public override void ApplyVisuals(float[][] lowerLayersHeight) {
    if (_mainVisualsThread != null && _mainVisualsThread.IsAlive) {
        _mainVisualsThread.Join();
    }

    Helpers.Swap(ref _vertices, ref _tempVertices); //swap the onces calculated by the _mainVisualsThread (temp) with the current array
    Helpers.Swap(ref _colors, ref _tempColors);

    _mesh.vertices = _tempVertices; //set the current as visual, the temps will be updated with the new vertices for next update
    _mesh.colors32 = _tempColors;

    _mainVisualsThread = new Thread(()=>
        UpdateVisuals(1, N, lowerLayersHeight, _height, _opaqueHeight, _nonZeroHeightOffset, _tempVertices, _tempColors)
        );
    _mainVisualsThread.Start();
}
```

So instead of updating the visuals this call, I let a separate thread calculate the visuals for the next time `ApplyVisuals` and apply the vertices and colors calculated by the previous call to `ApplyVisuals`. This of course makes the visuals lag behind one update, but that's an acceptable trade-of. Though for some reason this doesn't work. My mesh starts to flicker, one frame being the proper one, the next nothing. The picture shows the bad frame first, and then the good one.

[image]

The weirdness doesn't stop there however. In my first non-threaded solution, the simulation works perfectly. Though when I use threads the visualisation somehow fucks it up. Even though I don't alter any variables used in the simulation. The only thing I change is my buffered vertex and colors array, but those aren't used in the simulation.

The UpdateVisuals method I use:

```
static void UpdateVisuals(int xFrom, int xTo,
    float[][] lowerLayersHeight,
    float[][] heightField,
    float opaqueHeight,
    float nonZeroHeightOffset,
    Vector3[] vertices, Color32[] colors
    ) {

    // Set the heights of the vertices of the mesh and apply colors
    int x, y, index;
    float height, relHeight;

    for (x = xFrom; x <= xTo; ++x) {
        for (y = 0; y < N+2; ++y) {
            index = CalculateIndex(x,y);
            height = heightField[x][y];
            relHeight = height / opaqueHeight;

            vertices[index].y = height + lowerLayersHeight[x][y]
                + (height > 0 ? nonZeroHeightOffset : 0);
            colors[index].a = (byte)Mathf.Lerp(0, 200, relHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

In my simulation I never alter the `_height` array, what I do is I alter a `_tempHeight` array, and then swap them when the update is done. I do however read from the `_height` array.

Some more things I tried:
Another `ApplyVisuals` method:

```
    _mainVisualsThread = new Thread(()=>
        UpdateVisuals(1, N, lowerLayersHeight, _height, _opaqueHeight, _nonZeroHeightOffset, _tempVertices, _tempColors)
        );
    _mainVisualsThread.Start();
    _mainVisualsThread.Join();

    _mesh.vertices = _tempVertices;
    _mesh.colors32 = _tempColors;
```

This also works as it should. So there appears to go something wrong when actually doing other stuff while the visualsThread is working.

I also tried to copy both the `_height` and `lowerLayersHeight` with the copy from this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671179/987706) Like this:

```
    var bufferedHeight = Helpers.CopyArrayBuiltIn(_height);
    var bufferedLowerLayersHeight = Helpers.CopyArrayBuiltIn(lowerLayersHeight);
    _mainVisualsThread = new Thread(()=>
        UpdateVisuals(1, N, bufferedLowerLayersHeight, bufferedHeight, _opaqueHeight, _nonZeroHeightOffset, _tempVertices, _tempColors)
        );
```

This didn't help, and both the simulation and visualisation go wrong again :(

And then I was out of ideas. I'm pretty new to threading, so I'm hoping there's somthing simple I'm missing. But I can't figure out what.

---

Here's my simulation update code:

```
public override void DoUpdate(float dt, float dx, float[][] lowerLayersHeight) {
    // Wait for update to be done
    if (_mainUpdateThread != null && _mainUpdateThread.IsAlive) {
        _mainUpdateThread.Join();
    }

    Helpers.Swap(ref _tempHeight, ref _height);

    // Start the next update already on different threads. These will then be swapped next time an update is wanted.
    _mainUpdateThread = new Thread(()=> {
        // Height
        RunPartsThreaded(_threadCount, (int from, int to)=>UpdateHeight(from, to, dt, dx, _tempFlux, _height, _tempHeight));
    });
    _mainUpdateThread.Start();
}

static void UpdateHeight(int xFrom, int xTo, float dt, float dx,
    OutflowFlux[][] tempFlux,
    float[][] height,
    float[][] tempHeight
    ) {

    int x, y;
    float dV;

    for (x=xFrom ; x <= xTo ; x++ ) {
        for (y=1 ; y <= N ; y++ ) {
            //
            // 3.2.2 Water Surface (and Velocity Field Update)
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            dV = dt * (
                //sum in
                tempFlux[x-1][y].right + tempFlux[x][y-1].top + tempFlux[x+1][y].left + tempFlux[x][y+1].bottom
                //minus sum out
                - tempFlux[x][y].right - tempFlux[x][y].top - tempFlux[x][y].left - tempFlux[x][y].bottom
                ); //(6)
            tempHeight[x][y] = height[x][y] + dV / (dx*dx); //(7)
            //swap temp and the real one later
        }
    }
}
```

The code gets called every _dt seconds (usually 0.02-0.05) like this:

```
    _timeSinceLastUpdate += Time.deltaTime;
    if (_timeSinceLastUpdate >= _dt) {
        _timeSinceLastUpdate -= _dt;

        //
        // Update each layer
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ResetTotalHeight(); //The first layer just sits on a plane
        for (int i = 0; i < _layers.Count; ++i) {
            _layers[i].DoUpdate(_dt, _dx, _tempTotalHeight);
            _layers[i].ApplyVisuals(_tempTotalHeight);
            AddHeightToTotal(_layers[i].HeightField);
        }
    }
```

There are multiple layers, though only one uses the fluid simulation code, the others are static. The `AddHeightToTotal` is just a method to keep track of the total height of all previous layers, that's the `lowerLayersHeight` parameter my simulation methods get.

Lastly, the RunPartsThreaded method I use:

```
static void RunPartsThreaded(int threadCount, Action<int, int> partUpdateWrapper) {
    int extraThreadCount = threadCount - 1;
    Thread[] _threads = new Thread[extraThreadCount];
    int step = N / threadCount;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < extraThreadCount; ++i) {
        int index = i; //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352757/threadstart-in-a-loop-in-a-timer-only-executing-last-thread-in-said-loop
        _threads[index] = new Thread(()=>partUpdateWrapper(step * index + 1, step * (index+1)));
        _threads[index].Start();
    }
    partUpdateWrapper( step * extraThreadCount + 1, N );
    for (i = 0; i < extraThreadCount; ++i) {
        _threads[i].Join();
    }
}
```

The simulation can be run on only strips of my grid, and I make multiple threads each updating a different part of the whole grid.

Comment: Hey man :) I would say the problem is here: `In my simulation I never alter the _height array, what I do is I alter a _tempHeight array, and then swap them when the update is done`. Can you show the code?

Comment: Ok, updated my question with the code. There is still more, I for instance also have a _flux and _tempFlux array and that is updated on a similar way as the height (updated before the height.) Though that only reads, doesn't assign to neither the _height nor the _tempHeight arrays.

Comment: I just noticed the simulation also gets screwed a little, but only when my timestep is higher than 0.03 or so. It seems I'll have to do some more digging into what's going wrong there, hopefully it'll bring the solution for the visuals as well.

Comment: My instinct says this has something to do with the swapping. The way i see it is you are storing the new vertices in _tempVertices, then swap the arrays so that _tempVertices is the one you didnt use, but then assign exactly that one to _mesh.vertices . Is that the beahviour you want?

Comment: That's indeed true, that's not what's supposed to happen. The _temp ones are being filled with the new vertices. So you're correct, that's wrong. Though, even when I, after the swapping, use the non-temp (which now have the new vertices) the result is the same, bugged visuals as explained.

Comment: Sergey might be right here. You could try to use a lock to prevent multiple threads accessing _height at the same time.

Comment: Can reading from the _height array in multiple threads at once, even though it's not being altered, make it act strangely?

Comment: you are swapping arrays in one thread and use one of them in another, so you are not just reading. And i am not even sure just reading works in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preamble

I'm not very optimistic about your multi-threading design overall... IMO, it would be nice at least to have threads reused.

## Problem

Ok, take a look on this:

```
public override void DoUpdate(float dt, float dx, float[][] lowerLayersHeight) {
    ....
    Helpers.Swap(ref _tempHeight, ref _height);
```

Ooops! `UpdateVisuals` thread can be runnning right now (and it's highly likely that it is), which uses `_height` array.